# How to recognize if a string is an object?

Tags: javascript

I have to make a program where the user will input the name of an object with `prompt()` and after that all of the properties of the object will be listed.

Many students in my course are using `eval()`, but I've read that it's not a good idea to use this method.

So I tried to code something better but I haven't been able to complete it. My biggest problems are when the user writes `this.object` and when he writes `object.object.object` and the properties of the third object have to be displayed.

```
var x = prompt("Object?");
x = x.toLowerCase();

if (x === "window") {
    x = window;
    load_table();
} else if (window[x]) {
    x = window[x];
    load_table();
} else if (x[0] === "t" && x[1] === "h" && x[2] === "i" && x[3] === "s" && x[4] === ".") {
    x = x.split('.');
    x = x[1];
    load_table();
} else {
    document.write("Error Message.");
}
```

Any tip?

Comment: why would you be promoting use of `document.write`?

Comment: That's also a really strange way to check if a string begins with "this."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var x = prompt("Object?");
// x = x.toLowerCase(); // not including, what if the object has a capital in its name?
x = x.split('.');
if (x[0] == 'this') {
    x.shift(); // remove this, as it refers to window anyways
}
var theObj = window; // start with the global object
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    theObj = theObj[x[i]];
    if (theObj == undefined) break;
}
```

The variable `theObj` will contain your final value.

Comment: This will fail in the 'this' selector if I'm correct.

Comment: I don't know what the exact use case is for the person above. But in different closures the this variable will refer to different places then the window object. I start from the this object as you can go to window from this. And you still have access to the local variables.

Comment: In the OP's original code, when it starts with `this`, he strips it off and uses the global. (`this` is actually a keyword, not a variable, btw.)

Comment: Indeed sorry for the wrong wording. If fills the needed cases for him then i shut up ;) upvoted

Answer (score 1):

You might want a recursive function with a type checker. Then you might also want to write a function to check if the window objects has an object in it named like the value.

```
function check(val){
    if(!val) return "No value";
    else if(typeof val === "string"){
        return val;
    } else if(typeof val === "object"){
        var returner = "{";
        for(var i in val){
            returner += i + ": ";
            returner += check(val[i]);
            returner += ",";
        }
        return returner + "}"
    } else {
        return "Not object or string";
    }
}

function tellMe(string){
    if(string.split(".").length >= 2){
        var check = window;
        var split = string.split(".");
        for(var i = 0; i < split.length; i++){
            if(typeof check[string[i]] != "undefined"){
                check = window[string[i]];
            }
        }
        return "The closest value is " + check;
    } else if(typeof window[string] != "undefined"){
        return check(window[string]);
    } else {
        return "Value cannot be found in window object";
    }
}
```

### Example

```
var string = "A string";
var object = {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"};
console.log(tellMe("string"));
console.log(check(string));
console.log(tellMe("object"));
console.log(check(object));
```

Comment: This seems to be a JSON stringifier?

Comment: Not really, it just outpost something that looks similar to make the object readable. Its more like a console.log, actually :D

Comment: A (not so great) JSON representation, in other words. Which happens to not be what the OP wants, anyways. Try my answer. ;)

Comment: Probably true, was a long day. Added it into my code while you replied, but yeah. Too complex.